# Appending a binary file to another with c

Tags: c, file-io, binary

people of StackOverflow,
I'm pretty new to c and wanted to set myself a challenge:
Adding a binary file (like a .exe file) to another, so when the second one is started, bot files are executed. This is the code I tried:

```
FILE* fp1;
    FILE* fp2;


    fp1 = fopen("path_to_file1","rb");
    fp2 = fopen("path_to_file2","ab");

    fseek(fp1,0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(fp1);
    rewind(fp1);

    unsigned long buffer[size];





    fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,fp1);

    fclose(fp1);


    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,fp2);

    fclose(fp2);
```

All of this is running in the main function. 
The problem is when executing the code, instead of appending the first file to the second, it overrides the first one, and on execute only executes the second file.

I really hope you can help me :)

Comment: @KeineLust my goal is to execute both files when one of them is executed. I thought this is doable with just appending one file to another, but if someone got an easier solution to this, I'll be happy to take it :)

Comment: @Mr.SoUndso it doesn't work that way. You cannot append 2 executable files together. That just doesn't work.

Comment: if you want to execute one after another, just write a script.

Comment: I heard of a virus (and I'm not trying to create one myself), that was capable of appending itself to any .exe file it found to make it harder to remove it. I was one of the quite early viruses.

Comment: A virus does not append to the exe. It modifies the exe to insert itself in the segment list. It means that you have to be aware of the MZ/Elf file structure, otherwise it does nothing / corrupts the executable.

Comment: It is unclear whether the two executables are to be executed consecutively or concurrently. Serial vs parallel.

Comment: Okay, I'll put my plans to create a similar injection thing on ice for some time because that sounds really complicated. But thanks for your help everyone! :)

Comment: @Mr.SoUndso the disassembling+fixing assembly+reassembling technique isn't trivial, but at least you control the text and you can debug. I suggest you try that. And if my answer fits your needs, please accept it (and only in that case)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect because by doing this

```
unsigned long buffer[size];
```

you're writing `sizeof(buffer)` which is `sizeof(unsigned long)` times too big. So the first file is appended to the second file all right, but a lot of garbage is appended too.

You should declare:

```
unsigned char buffer[size];
```

so `sizeof(buffer)` yields the correct result.

Also, check the return value of your `fopen` statements.

EDIT: it just hit me that you want to append 2 executables together. The above (fixed) code works to append 2 binary files (data files) together, but for executables it just doesn't work.

Appending an executable in the end of another one is likely to be ignored by the operating system. The first executable header contains the logical size of the program segments. It doesn't read the file beyond that (well, it can be done by a lot of hacking and it's called a *virus*), which explains that your updated files runs like if nothing was appended.

One could imagine running a disassembler on both files, modify start points+add a wrapper to call both start points, and reassemble to another executable.

The easiest way to execute one program, then the other one, just call them in a script (bash, .bat, whatever) or in C `system` calls.

```
system("path_to_file1");
system("path_to_file2");
```